# Explanation for "Heisenberg" effect on SELECT before INSERT inside transaction? (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, transaction

I have a live database application of medium size (biggest table 40,000 rows) which has had a problem with transactions failing on a race condition.

There is a "Heisenberg" effect where if you look at the table before inserting data, there is a different result.

I've reduced the problem to the smallest single-table case which reproduces the difficulty: a table wich an `id` which we insert as -1 and then update to be `max(id)+1`, with an effect broadly similar to `auto_increment`.

**My question: what is the exact explanation of this? It appears to be about which operations block during a transaction and which do not.  Why does the `select` before the `insert` in Case 2 alter the result?**

In case 2, I would have expected the `select` to block, as its answer depends on the ongoing transaction in process 1.

Server version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04

## Case 1

```
drop table x;
create table x (id int primary key, s varchar(10));
insert into x set id = 10, s = 'ten';

PROCESS 1                            PROCESS 2

set autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
insert into x set id = -1, s = 'apple';
select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
-- @m is 11
update x set id = @m where id = -1;

                                     set autocommit = 0;
                                     start transaction;
                                     insert into x set id = -1, s = 'banana';
                                     -- PROCESS BLOCKED UNTIL PROCESS 1 COMMITS
commit;
exit;
                                     select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
                                     -- @m is 12
                                     update x set id = @m where id = -1;
                                     commit;
                                     exit;
```

The result is as expected:

```
+----+--------+
| id | s      |
+----+--------+
| 10 | ten    |
| 11 | apple  |
| 12 | banana |
+----+--------+
```

## Case 2

This case is exactly the same except process 2 does a `select * from x` before its `insert`:

```
drop table x;
create table x (id int primary key, s varchar(10));
insert into x set id = 10, s = 'ten';

PROCESS 1                            PROCESS 2

set autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
insert into x set id = -1, s = 'apple';
select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
-- @m is 11
update x set id = @m where id = -1;

                                     set autocommit = 0;
                                     start transaction;

                                     -- THE FOLLOWING SELECT IS THE EXTRA COMMAND
                                     select * from x;  -- only shows id 10

                                     insert into x set id = -1, s = 'banana';
                                     -- PROCESS BLOCKED UNTIL PROCESS 1 COMMITS
commit;
exit;
                                     select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
                                     -- @m is 11, not 12 as expected
                                     update x set id = @m where id = -1;
                                     -- ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Result of course doesn't have 'banana':

```
+----+-------+
| id | s     |
+----+-------+
| 10 | ten   |
| 11 | apple |
+----+-------+
```

## Edits

Per request in comments, here's `show create table x`

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Do you have the query cache on, by chance?

Comment: Server reports query_cache_type ON query_cache_wlock_invalidate OFF; will this affect the semantics of transaction locking?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can know whether `id` is unique.

Comment: @mustaccio - The QC purges _all_ entries for a table when _any_ row is inserted/modified in that table.  So, by brute force, the QC is irrelevant in this question.

Comment: @RickJames It's `id int primary key` in the question; `show create table` added.

Comment: @RickJames but "query_cache_wlock_invalidate OFF"? I mean, I personally would never enable the query cache anyway, so I'm just speculating, but when you shoot yourself in the foot, wouldn't you expect to see some holes in it?

Comment: @mustaccio I don't know anything about the QC, and have a default installation of MariaDB.  Are you suggesting that I should change some of these settings?

Answer (score 2):

`insert into x set id = -1, s = 'apple';` blocks the row with `id=-1` until then end of the transaction.  Hence the other process delays without deadlocking.

This is why you should worry about `max(id)+1`

```
PROCESS 1                            PROCESS 2

set autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
insert into x set id = -1, s = 'apple';
select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
-- @m is 11

                                     set autocommit = 0;
                                     start transaction;
                                     insert into x set id = -1, s = 'banana';
                                     select @m := max(id) + 1 from x;
                                     -- @m is 11
update x set id = @m where id = -1;
commit;
exit;
                                     update x set id = @m where id = -1;
                                     commit;
                                     exit;
```

Note how @m = 11 in both processes.

The solution in most cases is to tack `FOR UPDATE` on the end of any `SELECTs` that touch rows that you might modify or need to look at again later in the transaction.  Properly done, this should allow `max(id)+1` to work as desired.

Please note that there are a lot of subtle things going on with `AUTO_INCREMENT` that you cannot simulate with `max(id)`.

On the other hand, there are many situations where `AUTO_INCREMENT` will "burn" ids.  That is, a value will be reserved but not used.  This may be due to `ROLLBACK`, `IGNORE`, and several things.

Do you know about `last_insert_id()`?  That is how you safely grab the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value *after* an `INSERT`.  It does not even need an explicit `BEGIN..COMMIT`.  The value of the function is local to the connection, hence cannot be messed with by other connections or the QC.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you sure your example is right? P2 blocks on the `insert`, and so cannot progress until P1 has issued `commit`.  P2's `select` gives @m = 12.  This is case 1 of my question.  Case 2 with an extra select in P2 is where we get @m = 11.

Comment: If `id` is UNIQUE (such as via a PRIMARY KEY, then P2 will block waiting for access to the row with `id=-1`.

Comment: Yes, P2's `insert` blocks, and so we can't issue P2's `select` until after P1's `commit`.  I've cut and pasted your example but P2 gets @m = 12.  Many thanks for `select * from x FOR UPDATE`, which also blocks and makes my case 2 do what I'd expect.  But I still don't understand what it doesn't block without FOR UPDATE.

Comment: @jonathanjo - I added a new first paragraph.

Comment: In general, if touching a row, _other than with a plain `SELECT`_, blocks other _transactions_ from _modifying_ that row.  (There are exceptions.)  `INSERT` blocks; `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` blocks, but not quite as strongly.  "For update" means "I might modify this row later; please do not mess with it."

Comment: Many thanks.  I see I'm going to have to really read up on the details of the blocking. I think my question is really "why doesn't P2's `select * from x` block in Case 2?".  What does "not as strongly" mean?

Comment: In general, InnoDB tries to allow reads to proceed without blocking.  So multiple connections can be selecting the same data.  I suspect a "select for update" would not block a plain "select", but would block another "select for update".  (I am not sure.)  Also, transaction_isolation_mode matters.

Comment: @jonathanjo - I added a paragraph on `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: Many thanks: I'm familiar with all the `auto_increment` and `last_insert_id()` things: thsi isn't my difficulty.  I'm trying to get my transactions to work right, and this is just a simple example with the same race.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html has the info I need